# Getting the redirected page to show up in SERP instead of the target

Tags: seo, google, domains, redirects, 301-redirect

I have a site that is listed on a sitebuilder site with their own domain which in this example lets call this `siteA.com/myaccountnumber/index.html`.

I've purchased a domain `siteB.com` and I've setup a redirect from `B` to `A`... But I would like Google to index `siteB.com` rather than the one that is being redirected too using a standard 301.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google will and only indexes the destination page for several reasons, one being links on Google should transparent and people should know where they are going before they click.

If you want your main domain to appear in the results for your "keywords" on the shorter domain then post the content on that domain and not a redirecting domain. It should be simple enough to move the site over or ask the sitebuilder company if they offer this service where you can use your own domain (many do but requires a little fee).

Comment: I don't think your edited version of my  question is the same question. You're ok down to your last sentence but then you say " I would like Google to index siteB.com rather than the one that is being redirected too using a standard 301."  Google is going to index siteA without or without the 301. My question is how to get them to return the siteB url in the SERP rather than the siteA url, possibly using a canonical tag.

Comment: You want your domain to be listed rather than theres? your domain = B there domain = A your redirecting B to A because B is shorter... Setting up a canonical won't work if you have it redirecting. Basically the destination will always get preference regardless if a canonical is present or not. Feel free to edit my question and make it as simple as you can ;)

Comment: No, I think we're clear now. Basically, Google will always report content as belonging to the actual domain it's crawling, not a domain that points to it, and second, you can't get around this with a canonical. I think I need to do what you suggested - publish the site under B instead of A.  - Thanks